# SQL: How do I do an update that will only update the values that aren't null?

Tags: sql, sql-server, conditional-statements

How can I run an UPDATE like below where it only updates the columns that are not null?

```
UPDATE Table
   SET Name = @Name,
       Email = @Email,
       Phone = @Phone
 WHERE id = @id
```

Edit:

So if I'm using the above update but the following is assigned...

```
  @Name = Tom
  @Email = NULL
  @Phone = NULL
```

So only Name would be updated and whatever was in the database for Email and Phone will remain in the database as such.

Comment: You could use case statements to check for nulls, and return the original value if it was not null, and the new value if it is null.

Comment: Your first statement doesn't match your last, do you want to only update if the database values are not null or not update if the variables are not null?

Comment: Yes, the edit makes it seem like his initial question should have been, "How can I run an UPDATE like below where it only updates the columns where the new values are not null?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This basic idea should work:

```
UPDATE Table
   SET Name = ISNULL(@Name, Name),
       Email = ISNULL(@Email, Email),
       Phone = ISNULL(@Phone, Phone)
 WHERE id = @id
```

So if `@Name` is NULL, `Name` is unchanged. If `@Name` is **not** NULL, it is assigned to `Name` etc...

**--- EDIT ---**

Sure @clintp, the COALESCE variant would look like this:

```
UPDATE Table
   SET Name = COALESCE(@Name, Name),
       Email = COALESCE(@Email, Email),
       Phone = COALESCE(@Phone, Phone)
 WHERE id = @id
```

Comment: `COALESCE()` could also be used and is a standard.  There are small differences that won't really matter in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly:

```
SET Name = CASE WHEN Name IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE @Name END  ...
```

Comment: I believe the OP meant that when NULL values are passed for the *parameters*, they will be ignored. So swap your case statement around a little. :)

Comment: @djacobson you're right, blame it on the Friday evening gin and tonic.

Comment: @djacobson, nevertheless, on Saturday morning I see that the OP said "only updates the **columns** that are not null".  But whatever he meant, he should be able to work out a solution with the information in the answers here.